# Lie group invariants: are they infinitely differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory

In Bluman/Anco's text "Symmetry and Integration Methods for Differential Equations", on p. 46 we find the definition of *invariant function* **F**:

$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x^*})=\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})$, where **F** must be infinitely differentiable

On the same page this property is required to prove an important theorem (Theorem 2.3.4-1):

$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})$ is an invariant under Lie group of transformations if and only if $X\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})=0$, where $X$ is the infinitesimal group operator.

It appears that **F** must be infinitely differentiable in all its arguments (in jet space), because to prove the theorem he uses the relation

$$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x^*})=e^{\varepsilon X}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})+\varepsilon X \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})+\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon^2 X^2 \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})+...$$

which involves infinite differentiation of $\mathbf{F}$.

But I was also told by a math professor, that "a function that is invariant need not be infinitely differentiable."

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the plane $\Bbb R^2$ with the group of rotations $SO(2)$ acting on it. The function $f(\mathbf x) = \|\mathbf x\|$ on the plane is invariant, but definitely not smooth. (This generalizes immediately to dimension $n>2$.)

Comment: I agree about $||\mathbf{x}||$. What then about the theorem above. Is an invariant then _generally analytical_ , that is, analytical, except in such points as the origin in the example you give.

Comment: The theorem is crucial, and if **F** is not analytical, then $XF=0$ cannot be the necessary and sufficient condition for invariance. This would be a contradiction.

Comment: I have no idea what the theorem might be. But it seems the author is adding the hypothesis that his invariant function is smooth. Perhaps you need a further hypothesis in the group action (e.g., that the orbit space is a smooth manifold without boundary).

Comment: I added description of the theorem in the question above. I don't believe he makes smoothness assumptions, because in his textbook he gives a general study of invariants of Lie groups

Comment: It the theorem, he proves that $XF=0$ is the necessary and sufficient condition for invariance, which is a very general result

Comment: This seems like an "engineering-style" argument. The mathematical argument is just to use the definition of the Lie derivative $\mathscr L_X$, noting that $F$ is constant along the flow of $X$.

Comment: Ted, I truly appreciate your input. Only the text by Bluman/Anco is intro-level, and doesn't mention Lie derivative. From your example above I see that **F** is not $C^{\infty}$ but am trying to understand why not